# How to get facebook post timestamp/permalink from page html?

Tags: html, facebook, dom, timestamp

At facebook html feed, every single post* got element

```
div class="qzhwtbm6 knvmm38d"
```

which contains information about the date and a direct link to the post (post permalink). However, not always - sometimes this element does not contain information about date and link in the source code.

I do not fully understand how this element is structured - why after looking at the HTML source part, some of these fields contain this information and some do not? Even after clicking, they all redirect to the correct link/place. What it depends on? How do I get all the information for these items from the visible site?

*by single post i mean single

```
class="du4w35lb k4urcfbm l9j0dhe7 sjgh65i0"
```

element.

Comment: You know that those classnames can change at any moment and that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them?

Comment: Even if i scrap&parse 'em from my group for sell statistics? I was sure that it does not violate the rights of use.

Anyway - i know that they can change at any moment. But still curious why they aren't loaded with the page.